# is there a way to define a new (instead of aliasing) type in typescript?

Tags: types, typescript

If I define the following types:

```
type seconds = number;
type milliseconds = number;
```

The types are only *aliases* and the following syntax will not raise any error :

```
var x:seconds = 1;
var y:milliseconds = x;
```

While I expect typescript to prevent doing such assignment without a casting. Is there a way to create new nominal types ?

NB: I've found [this proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/364), not sure if there is anything new released since.

Comment: Why would you expect TS to prevent that? Typescript is structurally typed, and everything is structurally compatible in your example. And by generic types, you don't mean [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) types, right?

Comment: @Alex, you are right "generic" (or "templates" in C++) is ambiguous, a new "nominal" type would be more appropriated. I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

My answer is probably a better comment on @basarat's answer, but this would be too hefty of a comment, so I will leave it here anyway as you might find it handy.

There is another related proposal for nominal types here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202

In that discussion, Ryan Cavanaugh [has suggested using Branded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202#issuecomment-246507970) to get  approximately what you are looking for:

```
// Once
type Branded<T, U> = T & { '__ kind': U };

// Elsewhere
type OrderID = Branded<string, 'Order ID'>;
```

@basarat's trick is similar, but I couldn't get it to work with numbers.

So in your case, it would be:

```
type Branded<T, U> = T & { '__ kind': U };

type Milliseconds = Branded<number, 'Milliseconds'>;
type Seconds = Branded<number, 'Seconds'>;

let secondsValue: Seconds = <Seconds>5;
let millisecondsValue: Milliseconds = <Milliseconds>5;

secondsValue = millisecondsValue; // Error, just as you want

secondsValue = <Seconds>(secondsValue + secondsValue); // Works
secondsValue = secondsValue + secondsValue; // Doesn't work :(
secondsValue = <Seconds>(secondsValue + millisecondsValue); // Also works :(
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Once%0D%0Atype%20Branded%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20T%20%26%20%7B%20'__%20kind'%3A%20U%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Milliseconds%20%3D%20Branded%3Cnumber%2C%20'Milliseconds'%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20Seconds%20%3D%20Branded%3Cnumber%2C%20'Seconds'%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20secondsValue%3A%20Seconds%20%3D%20%3CSeconds%3E5%3B%0D%0Alet%20millisecondsValue%3A%20Milliseconds%20%3D%20%3CMilliseconds%3E5%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AsecondsValue%20%3D%20millisecondsValue%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%2C%20just%20as%20you%20want%0D%0A%0D%0AsecondsValue%20%3D%20%3CSeconds%3E(secondsValue%20%2B%20secondsValue)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Works%0D%0AsecondsValue%20%3D%20secondsValue%20%2B%20secondsValue%3B%20%2F%2F%20Doesn't%20work%20%3A(%0D%0AsecondsValue%20%3D%20%3CSeconds%3E(secondsValue%20%2B%20millisecondsValue)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Also%20works%20%3A(%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A)
So, it's not perfect, but you at least have to be intentional about assigning arbitrary numbers to each other, which is better than you get with type aliases.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a workaround, I am afraid (view it in [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%09interface%20Seconds%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09'These%20are%20seconds'%3A%20string%0D%0A%09%09value%3A%20number%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09interface%20MilliSeconds%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09'These%20are%20milliseconds'%3A%20string%0D%0A%09%09value%3A%20number%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09const%20s%20%3D%20%3CSeconds%3E%7B%20value%3A%203%7D%0D%0A%09const%20ms%20%3D%20%3CMilliSeconds%3E%7B%20value%3A%203%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09let%20wrong%3A%20Seconds%20%3D%20ms%0D%0A))

```
interface Seconds {
    'These are seconds': string
    value: number
}

interface MilliSeconds {
    'These are milliseconds': string
    value: number
}

const s = <Seconds>{ value: 3}
const ms = <MilliSeconds>{ value: 3}

let wrong: Seconds = ms // <= compilation error
```

Comment: Yes, that is also the workaround I've found, but definitely not something I want to use in production.

Comment: So, I am afraid the answer to your question is no... until the proposal on unit of measures becomes reality, if it ever does

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create new nominal types

You fundamentally have to break structural compatability. You've seen one way in bruno's answer. Another is to use enums:

```
// FOO
enum FooIdBrand {}
type FooId = FooIdBrand & string;

// BAR
enum BarIdBrand {}
type BarId = BarIdBrand & string;

/**
 * Usage Demo
 */
var fooId: FooId;
var barId: BarId;

// Safety!
fooId = barId; // error
barId = fooId; // error

// Newing up
fooId = 'foo' as FooId;
barId = 'bar' as BarId;

// Both types are compatible with the base
var str: string;
str = fooId;
str = barId;
```

Both ways are covered here https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html

Comment: that's very close to what I am looking for, however it does not seem to work with numbers. (replacing string to number does not raises any error on your //Safety! block) am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Since 2016, there is still no native support for this however a package `uom-ts` tries to simulate this behaviour. https://github.com/mindbrave/uom-ts here is their example:

```
import { Unit } from "uom-ts";

type Kg = Unit<{kg: 1}>;
type Pounds = Unit<{lb: 1}>;

const mass: Kg = 1.0 as Kg; // ok

const mass2: Kg = 1.0 as Pounds; // error
const mass3: Kg = 1.0; // error
```